# Validation and submit button don't function together in PartialView while using a composite model

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, razor, partial-views

Validation in my forms are defined in my Model.

If I don't include these two lines in my view:

```
$("#frmNewTemplate").removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#frmNewTemplate");
```

The submit button works fine, but validation doesn't work. If I include these, validation starts working and the submit button doesn't work anymore.

I try to do the validation through my model.

My model:

```
public class TemplateDTO : DTOBase
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="فيلد ضروري")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-z0-9\\-\\. ]+$", ErrorMessage = "کاراکترهاي وارد شده در محدوده کاراکترهاي مجاز نمي باشند")]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-zآ-ي0-9\\-\\. ]+$", ErrorMessage = "کاراکترهاي وارد شده در محدوده کاراکترهاي مجاز نمي باشند")]
        public virtual string Name_Fr { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<TemplateDetailsDTO> LstDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

My composite model:

```
public class TemplateViewModel
    {
        public TemplateDTO Template { get; set; }
        public List<TemplateFieldsDTO> TemplateFeilds { get; set; }
        public int[] oSelectedFieldsDTO { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool NextLine { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller (ActionResult which calls the view and JsonResult which is the answer):

```
public ActionResult _NewTemplate()
        {
            if (myGlobalVariables.AllTemplateFieldsDTO == null)
            {
                TemplateFieldsClientService oTemplateFieldsClientService = new TemplateFieldsClientService();
                myGlobalVariables.AllTemplateFieldsDTO = oTemplateFieldsClientService.GetAll();
            }
            TemplateDTO oTemplateDTO = new TemplateDTO();
            oTemplateDTO.LstDetails = new List<TemplateDetailsDTO>();
            TemplateViewModel x = new TemplateViewModel();
            x.TemplateFeilds = myGlobalVariables.AllTemplateFieldsDTO;
            x.Template = oTemplateDTO;
            return PartialView(x);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult _NewTemplate(TemplateViewModel oTemplateViewModel)
        {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (oTemplateViewModel.Template != null)
                    {
                        if (oTemplateViewModel.Template.Name == null)
                        {
                            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Parameter can not be null", "oTemplateDTO");
                        }
                        string strAttr = "";
                        if (oTemplateViewModel.NextLine)
                            strAttr = "\n";

                        List<TemplateDetailsDTO> LstTemDetails = new List<TemplateDetailsDTO>();

                        int Position = 0;
                        if (oTemplateViewModel.oSelectedFieldsDTO != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var i in oTemplateViewModel.oSelectedFieldsDTO)
                            {
                                TemplateDetailsDTO TempDetls = new TemplateDetailsDTO();
                                TempDetls.PositionNumber = ++Position;
                                TempDetls.Attributes = strAttr;
                                TemplateFieldsDTO OTemplateFieldsDTO = myGlobalVariables.AllTemplateFieldsDTO.Find(x => x.ID == i);
                                TempDetls.ObjFields = OTemplateFieldsDTO;
                                TempDetls.ObjTemplate = oTemplateViewModel.Template;
                                LstTemDetails.Add(TempDetls);
                            }
                        }
                        oTemplateViewModel.Template.LstDetails = LstTemDetails;
                        oTemplateClientService.AddNewTemplate(oTemplateViewModel.Template);
                        myGlobalVariables.AllTemplateDTO = oTemplateClientService.GetAllTemplate();

                        log.Info("Template added to Database.");
                        return Json(new { Result = "OK", Message = "عمليات ثبت با موفقيت انجام شد" }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json(new { Result = "Error", Message = "لطفا فيلدها را وارد نماييد" }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new { Result = "Error", Message = "لطفا فيلدها ي ضروري را وارد نماييد" }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
                }
        }
```

Code for my view:

```
@model IAC.SMS.MvcApp.Controllers.TemplateViewModel


<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {

            $("#frmNewTemplate").removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#frmNewTemplate");

        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            $('#ListBoxSource').find('option:selected').appendTo('#oSelectedFieldsDTO');
        })

        $('#btnDelete').click(function () {
            $('#oSelectedFieldsDTO').find('option:selected').appendTo('#ListBoxSource');
        });

        $('#btnUp').click(function () {
            var selectedOption = $('#oSelectedFieldsDTO').find('option:selected');
            var prevOption = $('#oSelectedFieldsDTO').find('option:selected').prev("option");
            if ($(prevOption).text() != "") {
                $(selectedOption).remove();
                $(prevOption).before($(selectedOption));
            }
        });

        $('#btnDown').click(function () {
            var selectedOption = $('#oSelectedFieldsDTO').find('option:selected');
            var nextOption = $('#oSelectedFieldsDTO').find('option:selected').next("option");
            if ($(nextOption).text() != "") {
                $(selectedOption).remove();
                $(nextOption).after($(selectedOption));
            }
        });

    });

    function display() {
        var dpt = document.getElementById("oSelectedFieldsDTO");
        if (dpt.options[dpt.selectedIndex].text == "Text") {
            document.getElementById("Text").disabled = false;
        }

    };
    function SelectAllItems() {
        $("#oSelectedFieldsDTO").each(function () {
            $("#oSelectedFieldsDTO option").attr("selected", "selected");
        });
    };

    //functions for ajax begin form
    function Refresh() {
        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ListTemplate", "Template")" + "/";
    }

    function Success(data) {
        if (data.Result == "OK") {
            jSuccess(
                                data.Message,
                                {
                                    autoHide: true, // added in v2.0
                                    clickOverlay: false, // added in v2.0
                                    MinWidth: 200,
                                    TimeShown: 1500,
                                    ShowTimeEffect: 1000,
                                    HideTimeEffect: 500,
                                    LongTrip: 20,
                                    HorizontalPosition: 'center',
                                    VerticalPosition: 'center',
                                    ShowOverlay: true,
                                    ColorOverlay: '#000',
                                    OpacityOverlay: 0.3,

                                });
            Refresh();
        }
        else {
            jSuccess(
                                data.Message,
                                {
                                    autoHide: true, // added in v2.0
                                    clickOverlay: false, // added in v2.0
                                    MinWidth: 200,
                                    TimeShown: 1500,
                                    ShowTimeEffect: 1000,
                                    HideTimeEffect: 500,
                                    LongTrip: 20,
                                    HorizontalPosition: 'center',
                                    VerticalPosition: 'center',
                                    ShowOverlay: true,
                                    ColorOverlay: '#000',
                                    OpacityOverlay: 0.3,

                                });
        }
    }
    function Fail() {
        jSuccess(
                            'ارتباط برقرار نشد',
                            {
                                autoHide: true, // added in v2.0
                                clickOverlay: false, // added in v2.0
                                MinWidth: 200,
                                TimeShown: 1500,
                                ShowTimeEffect: 1000,
                                HideTimeEffect: 500,
                                LongTrip: 20,
                                HorizontalPosition: 'center',
                                VerticalPosition: 'center',
                                ShowOverlay: true,
                                ColorOverlay: '#000',
                                OpacityOverlay: 0.3,

                            });
    }


    </script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_NewTemplate", "Template", new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = "Success",
            OnFailure = "Fail",
            LoadingElementId = "Loading"
        }, new { @id = "frmNewTemplate" }))
{
    <table id="tblDetails" class="dataInput" style="width:500px;">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        ليست مبدا
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        نام قالب
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Template.Name)
                    <label style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">*</label>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Template.Name)
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td rowspan="3">
                    @Html.ListBox("ListBoxSource", new SelectList(Model.TemplateFeilds, "ID", "Name", 1), new { size = 10 , style = "width:200px"})
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                    <label>
                        توضيحات
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Template.Name_Fr)
                </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        پيام تکميلي
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Text , new { disabled="disabled"})
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>

            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.CH_CheckBoxFor(model=>model.NextLine, "خط بعد", false, false)
            </td>

            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                    <button class="fixed button" id="btnAdd" type="button">اضافه<span class="left"></span> </button>
                    <button class="fixed button" id="btnDelete" type="button">حذف<span class="right"></span> </button>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                    <label>
                        ليست مقصد
                    </label>
                </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.oSelectedFieldsDTO, new SelectList(Model.Template.LstDetails, "ID", "Name", 1), new { size = 10, style = "width:200px", onchange = "display()" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="fixed button" id="btnUp" type="button">بالا<span class="up"></span> </button>
                    <button class="fixed button" id="btnDown" type="button">پايين<span class="down"></span> </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Template.ID)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <table>
            <tr> 
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <button class="fixed button" type="submit" onmouseover="SelectAllItems()">ذخيره</button>
                    </div>
                </td>                 
            </tr>
        </table>
}
```

Please tell me if I should include any more code.
My problem is that when I include the two lines code I mentioned above in my View to have validation, submit button in my PartialView won't function anymore, and the control doesn't go to the JsonResult function of my controller.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Update jquery.validate.min.js to version v1.12.0 - 4/1/2014 .
I hope you get the problem solved .